# A limiting form of 3D radial Dirac-delta function

Tags: limits, dirac-delta

Given a function of the form $$f(r;r_0) \propto \frac{e^{-r/r_0}}{r}$$, where $r$ is the radial coordinate in the spherical polar system. Can we show that in the limit $r_0 \rightarrow 0$, that this function tends a radial Dirac-delta function?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I tried and understood how the nascent delta functions work in 1D, but I can't understand how they will behave for a quantity which is 3D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distributional limit $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\frac{e^{-r/\varepsilon}}{r}$ is not the Dirac Delta.  Rather, we can show that

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\frac1{4\pi \varepsilon^2}\frac{e^{-|\vec r|/\varepsilon}}{|\vec r|}=\delta(\vec r)$$

To see this, let $\phi\in C_C^\infty$ and let $f(\vec r)=\frac{e^{-|\vec r|/\varepsilon}}{4\pi \varepsilon^2 |\vec r|}$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\langle f,\phi\rangle&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\mathbb{R
}^3} \frac1{4\pi \varepsilon^2}\frac{e^{-|\vec r|/\varepsilon}}{|\vec r|}\phi(\vec r)\,d^3r\\\\
&=\frac1{4\pi}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\mathbb{R
}^3} \frac{e^{-|\vec r|}}{|\vec r|}\phi(\varepsilon\vec r)\,d^3r\tag 1\\\\
&=\phi(0)\int_0^\infty re^{-r}dr\tag2\\\\
&=\phi(0)
\end{align}$$

where in going from $(1)$ to $(2)$ we appealed to the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

---

---

Note that we can establish a nascent Dirac Delta $\delta(\vec r-\vec r_0)$ by simply shifting coordinates.  That is to say, we have the distributional limit

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\frac{e^{-|\vec r-\vec r_0|/\varepsilon}}{4\pi \varepsilon^2|\vec r-\vec r_0|}=\delta(|\vec r-\vec r_0|)$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can you please comment under what limit it will converge to a general 3D dirac-delta function $\delta(\vec{r} - \vec{r}_0)$?

Comment: $r_0$ is the variable that goes to $0$ in your question ... but if you want something converging to $\delta(r-c)$, just replace $r$ by $r-c$ in your approximating function ...

Comment: @LL3.14 I am sorry, I think I didn't convey my question clearly, I understand that in the above scenario, the limit corresponds to $\delta(r-r_0)$, which is the condition for radial distance $r$ to be equal to $r_0$, but what about the case for the condition on vectors $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{r}_0$ (i.e. $\delta (\vec{r} - \vec{r}_0)$)

Comment: @user35952 The distribution $\frac1{4\pi \varepsilon^2}\frac{e^{-r/\varepsilon}}{r}$ has a distributional limit $\delta (\vec r)$.  All one needs to do is write $\frac1{4\pi \varepsilon^2}\frac{e^{-|\vec r-\vec r_0|/\varepsilon}}{|\vec r-\vec r_0|}$, which has distributional limit as $\varepsilon\to 0^+$ equal to $\delta(\vec r-\vec r_0)$

Comment: @user35952 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: @MarkViola I think the last equation will also give only a delta function over the magnitude $\delta (||\vec{r} - \vec{r}_0||)$ rather than the 3D delta function $\delta (\vec{r} - \vec{r}_0)$. I am trying to figure how the function I have given is related to 3D delta function.

Comment: @user35952 Note that $$\begin{align}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{e^{-|\vec r-\vec r_0|/\varepsilon}}{4\pi \varepsilon^2|\vec r-\vec r_0|}\phi(\vec r)d^3\vec r
&=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{e^{-|\vec r|}}{4\pi |\vec r|}\phi(\varepsilon\vec r+\vec r_0)d^3\vec r\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{DCT}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left(\frac{e^{-|\vec r|}}{4\pi |\vec r|}\phi(\varepsilon\vec r+\vec r_0)\right)d^3\vec r\\\\
&=\phi(\vec r_0)
\end{align}$$So, this distributional limit is indeed  $\delta(\vec r-\vec r_0)$

Comment: @MarkViola I know it's been a long time, but just wanted to clarify, given the previous comment, shouldn't the RHS of the first equation in the answer be $\delta (\vec{r})$ rather than $\delta (|\vec{r}|)$?

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks for clarifying. But I am confused due to the formula given here (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html), in eq. 51- dirac delta function in spherical polar coordinates. In this case, there is an additional $1/(2\pi r^2)$ in the formula. Can you please clarify this part?

Comment: @user35952 Yes, you are correct.  The first expression is indeed $\delta(\vec r)$. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: @user35952 You're welcome.  My pleasure.